# DefaultExecutor not to wait for result (asynchronous call)

Tags: java, executorservice

Is there a way to tell Apache DefaultExecutor not to wait for result and go on with code? Currently, it waits for a called program or script to terminate.

Comment: Use the asynchronous call: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/exec/DefaultExecutor.html#execute(org.apache.commons.exec.CommandLine, java.util.Map, org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteResultHandler)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DefaultExecutor has methods for asynchronous execution.

[without environment](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/exec/DefaultExecutor.html#execute(org.apache.commons.exec.CommandLine,%20org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteResultHandler)) :

```
public void execute(CommandLine command, ExecuteResultHandler handler) 
                                               throws ExecuteException, IOException
```

and

[with environment argument](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/exec/DefaultExecutor.html#execute(org.apache.commons.exec.CommandLine,%20java.util.Map,%20org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteResultHandler))

```
public void execute(CommandLine command, Map<String,String> environment, ExecuteResultHandler handler)
         throws ExecuteException, IOException
```

If you want to ignore the results, you can pass a no-op implementation of the ExecuteResultHandler.