# Java app spawns an application and ends. Application is sometimes also killed

Tags: java, windows, spawn

I have a Java app which is used solely to start one of a number of applications. It is registered as a protocol handler and is used in the company portal to start applications from within a browser.

This has worked quite well until recently. As more people are working from home, access to network resources has become noticably slower.

My suspicion is that the application is started but the Java app exits before the application becomes a separate process. As a result, the application does not start.

I added a `Sleep` before exiting which does help if set to a value greater than 1 second.

Is my suspicion correct? Is there a way to ensure that the new process has started before exiting?

```
DefaultExecuteResultHandler handler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onProcessFailed(ExecuteException e) {
        log.error("Process failed: " + cmdLine.toString());
        log.error("Message", e);
        super.onProcessFailed(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProcessComplete(int exitValue) {
        log.info("Process complete: " + cmdLine.toString());
        log.info("Exit code " + exitValue);
        super.onProcessComplete(exitValue);
    }
};

DefaultExecutor exec = new DefaultExecutor();
exec.execute(cmdLine, handler);

log.info("Process started");

Thread.sleep(1000); // give process time to start

log.info("Exiting");
            
return RET_OK;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are starting the DefaultExecutor asynchronously; see other question [DefaultExecutor not to wait for result (asynchronous call)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25921378/defaultexecutor-not-to-wait-for-result-asynchronous-call)
and documentation http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/exec/DefaultExecutor.html#execute(org.apache.commons.exec.CommandLine,%20org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteResultHandler)

You have to check in your handler the possible end or start the Executor without a handler, so it is synchronous - see http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/exec/DefaultExecutor.html#execute(org.apache.commons.exec.CommandLine)

Comment: As I understand it, starting synchronously will keep both processes alive until the spawned process ends. Ideally, I would like the spawning process to end once the spawned process has started - not when it ends.

Comment: But in your provided code you are just using the child process to call something else - I asume there you are starting again some program?! That's why the other program doesn't get killed after the parent stops. If you would really start the other process as child it would also be killed as soon as the parent gets killed, that was the case in your problem discription as the parent got killed before the child got the target process started.